# printing a vector in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I made a function that reads elements in a vector and a function that prints the elements. The problem is that the print function doesn't work well.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
```

1)

```
int read()
{
    int elements,i;
    cout<<"Give the number of elements:";
    cin>>elements;
    int v[elements];
    for(i=1;i<=elements;i++)
    {
        cout<<"v["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>v[i];
    }
    return elements;
}
```

2)

```
void print_vector(int elements)
{
    int i;
    int v[elements];
    for(i=1;i<=elements;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n=read();
    print_vector(n);
    return 0;
}

Example:
Give the number of elements:5
v[1]=1
v[2]=2
v[3]=3
v[4]=4
v[5]=5
1348
```

It prints 1348 instead of 12345. What is wrong with the function and how can I modify it to print the right elements?

Comment: Your code is using a compiler extension. Use `std::vector` instead of that variable-length array.

Comment: Please read [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and follow advice.

Answer (score 3):

```
int v[elements];
```

This create a fresh array of integers.

It is relatively difficult to pass around arrays, as you have to be careful how you handle the allocation of memory, and they hark back to the old days of `C`.

As you're learning `C++` you can use a `class` to manage memory issues. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is syntactically similar to an array, but looks after allocation and resizing for you, and remembers what size it is, too.

You can pass objects into functions by reference `&`, and inside the function it will be able to modify the passed in object, and have a lasting effect after the function has finished.

```
void read(vector<int>& elements) {
    // in here you can resize the vector
}

void print(const vector<int>& elements) {
    // passing in elements by const reference means you can't modify it
}
```

So altogether:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> elements;
    read(elements);
    print(elements);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be object oriented, you should be looking for ways of grouping data and functions together, so that you avoid passing around data altogether. In this case you can group the vector and the read and print functions. Maybe call it `UserIntegers`:

```
class UserIntegers {
public:
    void process() {
        read();
        print();
    }
private:
    vector<int> numbers;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    UserIntegers userIntegers;
    userIntegers.process();
}
```

Comment: And how should I design the print function so it doesn't create a new array of integers?

Answer (score 2):

You have errors in your print function

```
for(i=1;i<=elements;i++)
{                   //^^^^^
    cout<<v[i];
    ++i;  //You would like to skip some elements?
}
```

You increment index i twice and array index starts from 0, not 1; it ending on number (elements-1) not elements, meanwhile, you are using array, not vector.

Answer (score 2):

In `read()`, you read the elements into a local array `v`. When the function ends, the array will go away as well. The same happens in `print_vector()`.

Another error is the indexing of your array. You access the elements from `1` to `elements` inclusive, which ignores the first element `0` and accesses finally one element beyond the array bounds (`elements`).

You need to allocate an array, better a `std::vector`, outside of both functions and pass that into `read()` for filling and into `print_vector()` for printing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void read(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    int elements,i, n;
    std::cout<<"Give the number of elements:";
    std::cin>>elements;
    for(i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"v["<<i<<"]=";
        std::cin>> n;
        v.push_back(n);
    }
}

void print_vector(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    read(v);
    print_vector(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the template argument for std::vector